# How To return the true condition only of a result on a list in r?

Tags: r, boolean, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I have a problem with my R code.

Here, I have a list named **bought_list** with lists of **customer** and **checkout** (checkout is a data frame),

And this how **checkout** lists looks like:

```
items      price qty  total
Milk       10    2    20
Dolls      15    10   150
Chocolate  5     5    25
Toys       50    1    50
```

I want to know which one is for **play_purpose** and **date_purpose**
So I made a variable of boolean

```
play_purpose <- Bought_list[["checkout"]][,"total"] >= 50 & Bought_list[["checkout"]][,"total"] <= 150
date_purpose <- Bought_list[["checkout"]][,"total"] > 0 & Bought_list[["checkout"]][,"total"] < 50
```

How to return the items name and total value of selected condition like this?

for play_purpose:

```
Dolls 150
Toys  50
```

for date_purpose :

```
Milk      20
Chocolate 25
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on the structure of your data, but you could subset with your current code:

```
play_purpose <-
  Bought_list[["checkout"]][Bought_list[["checkout"]][, "total"] >= 50 &
                              Bought_list[["checkout"]][, "total"] <= 150, c(1, 4)]

#  items total
#2 Dolls   150
#4  Toys    50

date_purpose <-
  Bought_list[["checkout"]][Bought_list[["checkout"]][, "total"] > 0 &
                              Bought_list[["checkout"]][, "total"] < 50, c(1, 4)]

#      items total
#1      Milk    20
#3 Chocolate    25
```

Another option is to use `dplyr`:

```
Bought_list$checkout %>% 
  filter(total >= 50 & total <= 150) %>% 
  select(items, total)

Bought_list$checkout %>% 
  filter(total > 0 & total < 50) %>% 
  select(items, total)
```

Or if you are needing to applying this function to multiple dataframes in the list, then we could use `map` from `purrr`:

```
map(Bought_list, ~ .x %>% 
  filter(total >= 50 & total <= 150) %>% 
  select(items, total))

map(Bought_list, ~ .x %>% 
  filter(total > 0 & total < 50) %>% 
  select(items, total))
```

**Data**

```
Bought_list <- list(checkout = structure(list(items = c("Milk", "Dolls", "Chocolate", 
"Toys"), price = c(10L, 15L, 5L, 50L), qty = c(2L, 10L, 5L, 1L
), total = c(20L, 150L, 25L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```

Comment: Note that you cannot use the `map` function. the Bought list contains the customer tible which probably does not have the total column, nor the items column. You probably want to stick with the first code or use the filter but only on the checkout list and not on the bought list